# pip for Python Installation issues

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, pip, bootstrapper

When I go to install pip for python 2.7. I click on the get pip link, and the site loads a bootstrap pip site explaining the binary data instead of a downloadable site. When I try to download it from the site by entering python get-pip.py in my powershell, I get [Errno 2] No such file or directory in my power shell. I have tried using cmd as an administrator and entering python get-pip.py but still the same [Errno 2]. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link for convenience: 
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Create a file on your computer called get-pip.py and copy the contents of the above link to that file and then run it using `python get-pip.py`.

That will install pip on your computer.